# What's the point of jQuery selectors containing < and >?

Tags: jquery

I once saw a jQuery selector that went like this:

```
$('<h1>').someAction();
```

I've read that this is supposed to create an HTML element instead of select it. Is that true? And if yes, what's the point at all of doing this?

Comment: Can you add exact code where you've seen this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it'll create new HTML element, For example you can create an `h1` and set some text inside it like this -

`var $myH1 = $('<h1>').text('Some H1 Text !!');`

Note that this HTML element is not there in DOM yet, This is just a jQuery Object. To add this in DOM,

`$('body').append($myH1);`

Answer (score 0):

It indeed does create an element. It's a shorter syntax than regular javascript's `document.createElement("h1")` and you can use jQuery functions right away:

```
$("<h1>").text("Hello World").click(function() {...}).appendTo("body");
```

It's super convenient.

You can also construct and create whole HTML DOM fragments using this function:

```
$("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(...)` function has three main purposes.

1. select existing DOM elements, as you point out.
2. create DOM fragments.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2
   This allows the developer to create a complex, event-handled set of elements before attaching it to the DOM itself.  This is better for performance and writing reusable code.
3. Much less known/used, to setup a document-ready-like callback.